# How to find update time in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Are there any command to find when an specific record of a table updates  in oracle.
I want to detect sequence of updating a record in oracle.

Comment: I don't know if there is way to do that, but if you have a long term need for this, then add a last updated timestamp column to the table.  And by the way, you may not even need to physically delete the record, if you use something called "soft delete."  With soft delete, a record is marked as deleted without physically removing it.

Comment: I have updated timestamp column but when a user update directly from database this field does not help me

Comment: You can create a virtual column in that table, which would be "calculated" as following: Each time a record gets inserted/updated, it would append the sysdate at the end of it - thus giving you a history of inserts/updates. You can put words like "ins", "upd" at the start of each date to indicate the operation. Have in mind to put some logic, which would truncate the value, when it reaches the max permitted for that column ... Just as an idea

Comment: Ok, quick and dirty one - `ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD hist_col clob GENERATED ALWAYS AS (hist_col || to_clob(sysdate))  VIRTUAL`. Why clob - so you don't care how many times it gets updated (4Gigs of text ... hmm some millennia of updates). You don't need the "ins", "upd" keywords actually, because only the first one will be the "inserting one" and all of the rest would be the "updating ones".

Comment: @g00dy When I run your command in psql "ORA-54003: specified data type is not supported for a virtual column
" is raised

Comment: Ok, scalar datatypes it is - change the word "clob" to "varchar2(4000)" - that's going to be ok. The expression should be: `ALTER TABLE yourTable ADD hist_col varchar2(4000) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (substr(hist_col || to_char(sysdate) || '; ', -4000)) VIRTUAL`. 4000 should be enough + there's a substring which would get the last 4000 if it exceeds it some day.

Comment: I deleted my comment, as not possible to create such a column. The solution here is with a Trigger and nothing else

Comment: @g00dy then after fixing the datatype you get `ORA-54012: virtual column is referenced in a column expression`

Comment: @rezaramezanimatin. You need to look for `ORA_ROWSCN` Pseudocolumn. Check my post below.

Answer (score 1):

There is not way directly. Maybe you can use Oracle Flashback Technologies. So,  you can see older version of rows.

Default it can keep 900 seconds(15 minutes) history for each table. You can increase it and guarantee to keep. But ensure you have enough space.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a good alternative over fixing the table design problem.

Answer (score 1):

> to find when an specific record of a table updates in oracle

You need to know about `ORA_ROWSCN`. For each row, `ORA_ROWSCN` returns the conservative upper bound system change number (SCN) of the most recent change to the row. This pseudocolumn is useful for determining approximately when a `row was last updated`.

Read more [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/pseudocolumns007.htm#SQLRF51145).